# Valid RegEx doesn't work with ASP.Net MVC RegularExpression attribute

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I have a regular expression to validate password rules.

In a .Net Console application, it is correctly rejecting or validating passwords as expected.

```
var strongRegex = new Regex("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])");
Console.WriteLine(strongRegex.IsMatch("Test_1234"));
```

This returns "true", as expected.

When I add this to my model in an ASP.Net MVC project, this same value is being rejected by jQuery's unobtrusive validation on the client.

```
[RegularExpression("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])"]
```

I viewed the page source to see how this is being rendered due to reading about case-sensitivity issues in prior framework versions, but that doesn't seem to be the case here ... it renders the following on the `input` element:

`data-val-regex-pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])"`

And this causes the same value that works in the console application ("Test_1234") to fail client-side validation.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? Seems to be valid, you can verify here 
https://regex101.com/r/ZQrWJO/1

Comment: @AlfredoA. Very sure.  It is blocking me with jQuery's unobtrusive validation and shows the Message property if I include it with the `RegularExpression` attribute.  I don't see an issue either.

Comment: This seems more of a JavaScript/JQuery issue.  You may want to add additional tags

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test with your expression?

Comment: Your regex consists of assertions only. Try it also matching for example `.*` like  `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]).*$`

Comment: @Thefourthbird That fixed it, thanks.  Why did it work in the console app and not in the MVC app?  Add that as an answer with an explanation, I'll accept.

Comment: @Patrick - Javascript and .NET use slightly different regex interpreters.  For use with Javascript, test out your expressions with Skinner's tool at https://regexr.com/

Comment: Side note:  The last bit--`[^a-zA-Z0-9]`--allows anything to be put in as a valid character. This includes the control characters that are at the start of ASCII and anything in the Unicode set that comes above ASCII. Is this what you intended?

Comment: To @KennethK.'s point, a \W is probably a better choice, but they are the OP's rules.

Comment: @ClayVerValen That has the same effect except that it prevents underscores (and a few other non-English characters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your password validation rules are:

1. Must have at least 1 digit
2. Must have at least 1 upper case character
3. Must have at least 1 lower case character
4. Must have at least 1 other character that doesn't match one of the first three rules.

If I am reading this right, try this:

```
^((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])).*
```